# Live Video player

Tags: iphone

i want to create a Live Video Player.. can any one suggest how to make or any SDk available for live Streaming Video Player

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=live+streaming+to+iphone

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Live Streaming to iPhone
http://geobray.com/2010/03/26/live-tv-streaming-to-iphone-with-http/

or this

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=live+streaming+to+iphone

Answer (score 0):

The native iOS MPMoviePlayerController also supports streaming.
There's plenty of information about it on Google and particularly on Apple's [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767)

Answer (score 0):

As Hagai said,
You can play the lie streaming using MPMoviePlayerController

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"LIVE STREAM LINK"]];
// video player
MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
playerViewController.contentURL = url;
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[playerViewController play];
```

Thats all you need to perform